# Generic 3D Volumetric Plot in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly

I'd like to quickly visualise some 3D volumetric data (just a regular 3d tensor).
Are there any generic packages that will automatically make these types of plots? Ideally I'd like a slider that would allow me to slice through the volume.

Something like this will be great but somehow I can't get the example to work (trying to walk through the example results in "Authentication credentials were not provided." and it looks a bit complicated):
https://plot.ly/python/visualizing-mri-volume-slices/

Comment: Check out `scikit-image`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick walkthrough of how plotly online works!

First create an account in the [plotly official site](https://plot.ly/)

Then after logging in, go to **Settings -> API Key -> Regenerate**, this will give you a new API key. From the page, you need to get your **"User Name" and "API key"**

I am not sure which editor you are using, but make the following change and the graph will get generated.

**Before:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
```

**After:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='<<Your username goes here>>', api_key='<<Your API key goes here>>')
```

Please let me know if this solves your issue too!

Comment: Thanks. But now when I try to run the demo it says "This file is too big! Your current subscription is limited to 524 KB uploads.". Are there any free packages for doing something similar?